# Дерево. Проблема с заполнением

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
int a;
node *left, *right;
};
void Show(node *tree);
void Push(int x,node *&tree);
int main()
{
node *tree = NULL;
int k, num;
cout << "Input the number of elements" << endl;
cin >> k;
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    cout << "Input the element" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    Push(num,tree);

}
Show(tree);

_getch();
return 0;
}
void Push(int x,node *&tree)
{

node *tmp = new node;
tmp = tree;
node **current = &tree;
bool flag = false;
if (tree == NULL)
{
    tree = new node;
    tree->a = x;
    tree->left = tree->right = NULL;
    return;
}
while (!flag)
{
    if (x > tmp->a)
    {
        if (tmp->right != NULL)
        {

            tmp = tmp->right;

        }
        else
        {
            /**/
            *current = tmp;
            tmp->right = new node;
            tmp->right->left = tmp->right->right = NULL;
            tmp->right->a = x;
            (*current)->right = tmp->right;
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (tmp->left != NULL)
        {
            tmp = tmp->left;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp->left = new node;
            tmp->left->left = tree->left->right = NULL;
            tmp->left->a = x;
            tree = tmp;
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    }

}
void Show(node *tree)
{
if (tree != NULL)
{
    Show(tree->left);
    cout << tree->a << " ";
    Show(tree->right);
}
}
```

Делал заполнения дерева с помощью рекурсии а теперь попытался через цикл ..
Но есть проблема, я нахожу место куда надо вставить элемент но не могу создать связь.